# meaning or interpretation of square factorial term

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am dealing with a combinatorial-related problem.

For N particles in an M spaces lattice, the binomial coefficient tells us how many ways we can arrange the N particles
${M \choose N}=\frac{M!}{N!(M-N)!}$

In the problem, I am actually working: asymmetric exclusion process (ASEP) a term recurrently appear that is

$$\frac{M!^2}{N!^2(M-N)!^2}$$
is there any physical interpretation for such term beyond saying it's ${M \choose N}^2$ ??

Comment: I mean... saying its $\binom{M}{N}^2$ is already saying quite a lot.  You could artificially construct an example counting problem for this with that as the answer like "Given an urn with $M$ distinctly labeled red balls and another urn with $M$ distinctly labeled blue balls how many ways can you select $N$ red and $N$ blue balls?"

Comment: If you have an $M\times M$ square lattice, it’s the number of ways to choose an $N\times N$ sublattice of the form $A\times B$, where $|A|=|B|=N$.

Comment: In general, probably not.  But the fact that all the individual factorial terms are squared suggests that it may be fruitful to treat the number of arrangements as the thing that's being squared.